# Creating Java standalone program with Eclipse, 32 vs 64 bit platforms

Tags: java, eclipse, 32bit-64bit

After reading many related posts on stackoverflow, I still haven't been able to find a solution to my question. If this question has already been asked, please kindly provide the link.

I am new to creating a Java standalone program with GUI in Eclipse. 
My development platform has 64-bit Windows 7, 64-bit JRE, 64-bit JDK and 64-bit Eclipse.
The program has to be able to run on both 32-bit and 64-bit Windows 7 / JRE.

Will there be any compatibility issues if I run my program on a 32-bit Windows 7/ JRE platform? What kind of GUI plugin for Eclipse do I need to use in order to avoid the potential compatibility issues, if any?

Thank you for you help.

Comment: Except for memory issues (32 Bit JVMs cannot manage as much memory as 64 bit JVMs can), I do not see immediate problems, as long as you stick to Java-only programming. I.e., do not use any platform-specific libraries, e.g. made with Swig.

Comment: DaDaDom, thanks for your advice! Do you know if the Swing and WindowBuilder plugins are platform-specific which would cause potential compatibility issues?

Comment: When you say "standalone program", what do you mean exactly? Just a JAR file? Or an EXE file built by something like JET or Avian?

Comment: I want it to be an exe file - the user just clicks it and it will run without the need of any Internet connection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Be sure that a 32 bit JVM will run the application using 32 bit constraints and a 64 bit JVM will run the same application using 64 bit constraints. This is handled automatically and it means that a java application is not tied to the platform over which it is compiled. Hence, it does not make any difference to have a Java application developed and compiled over 32-bit or 64-bit machines. It should be machine-independent; **unless you have some native library dependency or the java code is directly being compiled to native code**.

There will not be any potential compatibility issues and you DO NOT require any tools (which dont exist by the way) to keep your application safe from such issues. The java platform takes care of the same itself.

Comment: Bhoot, thanks for your advice! Do you see any compatibility issues if I use Swing or WindowBuilder as the GUI plugin? I am not sure if they have any native library dependency.

Comment: Not at all. There will be no compatibility issues. Your GUI will be using java swing which is platform independent.